# Get stream_autocomplete_0_GUID of outlook 2010 and further versions using c#

Tags: c#, outlook, autocomplete

I want to figure out the GUID of the stream_autocomplete_0 file for all logged in accounts in outlook 2010 and further versions by using c# code. I searched it for long time but I didn't get any solution for the same can anybody help me out.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What stream autocompete guid? Autocomplete is stored in a binary MAPI property in a hidden (associated) message or in the registry.

Comment: When we configure outlook 2010 and further versions and send a mail to account at the backend on the path C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\RoamCache a file named as stream_autocomplete_0_(GUID) gets generated and for each logged in account new GUID and new stream_autocomplete_0 file gets generated so I want to figure out which GUID is connected with which account.